# Controlling an arduino robot using raspberry pi after the pairing has been done

Tags: c

Does raspberry pi have any inbuilt Bluetooth libraries? Can I just call a bluetooth function when I'm programming in C to control a robot?
I've already paired the arduino robot.

Comment: You can use a Bluetooth dongle and use some libraries for that. You can use a full debian linux on the raspberry.

Comment: okay.
How can open and read from dev/rfcomm file in C code ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example here: [Bluetooth-with-c](http://www.cs.grinnell.edu/~walker/bluetooth-with-c/development-notes.shtml)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char message[9];
  int i;
  FILE * robot = fopen ("/dev/rfcomm0", "w");

  // send a message
  int duration, frequency;
  message[0]=113; // set speaker
  duration = 2000; // 2000 milleseconds = 2 seconds
  message[1]= duration >> 8;  // high-order 8 bits
  message[2]= duration % 256;  // low-order 8 bits
  frequency = 880; // A above middle C
  message[3]= frequency >> 8; // high-order 8 bits
  message[4]= frequency % 256;// low-order 8 bits
  message[5]= -1 ; // end of data set
  message[6]= 0;   // not used
  message[7]= 0;   // not used
  message[8]= 0;   // not used
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    fputc(message[i], robot);

  message[0]=113; // set speaker
  duration = 3000; // 3000 milleseconds = 3 seconds
  message[1]= duration >> 8;  // high-order 8 bits
  message[2]= duration % 256;  // low-order 8 bits
  frequency = 440; // A near middle C
  message[3]= frequency >> 8; // high-order 8 bits
  message[4]= frequency % 256;// low-order 8 bits
  message[5]= -1 ; // end of data set
  message[6]= 0;   // not used
  message[7]= 0;   // not used
  message[8]= 0;   // not used
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    fputc(message[i], robot);

  fclose(robot);
  return 0;
}
```